# MYSQL Join Multiple times on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull both owner and editby. Both of those fields are INT. Inside a simple table, for example:

users:

```
user_id user_name
-----------------
2       johnny
3       mecca
```

doc:

```
owner content editby
----------------------
2     misc    3
```

SQL:

```
SELECT doc.owner, doc.content, doc.editby, users.user_name
FROM doc
LEFT JOIN
    users
ON
users.user_id = doc.owner
WHERE 
    doc_id = $id
```

I can grab owner user_name, but I am not sure how to obtain editby on the same table. How do I go about pulling the different user names for different id fields multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the `users` table twice with different aliases

```
SELECT doc.owner, doc.content, 
       e.user_name as editor, 
       o.user_name as owner 
FROM doc
LEFT JOIN users o ON o.user_id = doc.owner
LEFT JOIN users e ON e.user_id = doc.editby
WHERE doc_id = $id
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept it as answer when it permits.